# Simple R Loop query

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to write a simple R code, using a loop, to generate the following data

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
```

I tried writing this but it doesn't work

```
container = numeric(6)

for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    container[i]  <- cbind(i,j)
  }
}
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your expected output is not reproducible and ambiguous. Do you want a data.frame, string vector, or something else? `container` currently is a numeric vector and you are trying to assign a 1x2 matrix into a spot where a single number goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your current code:

```
container = matrix(numeric(12), ncol = 2)
row <- 1
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    container[row,]  <- cbind(i,j)
    row <- row + 1
  }
}

container
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    2    1
[5,]    2    2
[6,]    2    3
```

Comment: Why not simplify `container[row,]  <- cbind(i,j)` to `container[j,]  <- cbind(i,j)` and remove `row <- row + 1`

Comment: Thanks, I see that now. For the sake of making the code unreadable you could try `container[(i-1)*3+j,] <- cbind(i,j)`